# Populating listview through runtime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am creating a listview and the items and subitems are being fetched from the database. However, when I'm running my solution the listview only displays the id. I want to dynamically add columns and rows to make it like a datagrid. here's my code.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table = logic.ViewInfo();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        ListViewItem myList;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            myList = new ListViewItem();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    myList.Text = row.ItemArray[i].ToString();
                else
                    myList.SubItems.Add(row.ItemArray[i].ToString());
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(myList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's the requirement in my job. to use listview for more eye friendly UI.

Comment: For the first row, examine the number of columns and add columns to the list view for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see only an ID is that you don't have proper columns.
You can add them in designer or in a code.
As you need it to be added "dynamically", you need to add as many columns, as values you have in an `ItemArray`.

Try this code. It is working for me.
There is no need in using `Text` property. Each `SubItem` stands for a cell.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = logic.ViewInfo(); // Combine declaration and assignment
    listView1.View = View.Details; // Better place it in designer 

    listView1.Columns.Clear();
    foreach (var column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
         listView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName); // or Caption, or anything else
    } 

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem myList = new ListViewItem(); // Move declaration into inner scope. You are reinitializing reference type variable each type. In my opinion, it is not good.
        for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // You don't need Text property
            myList.SubItems.Add(row.ItemArray[i].ToString());
        }
        listView1.Items.Add(myList);
    }
}
```